# Does localStorage get reset when I recompile native modules?

Tags: electron, local-storage, native-module, electron-rebuild

I recently had to update a native module in my electron project.
Just to be sure to have a clean installation I first removed all node_modules and reinstalled them via npm install. Then I rebuilt my native module via [electron-rebuild](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-rebuild)

After starting my app, I figured that the localStorage had been reset and all my data had been lost.

Now I am confused. Do I need to worry about localStorage being reset when sending app updates to my clients?

Comment: What information are you storing in `localStorage`? If it's that important that you are concerned about loosing it you maybe want to store that sort of data in an separate config or even data file

Answer (score 4):

The localStorage does not get lost. By default Electron will store the files (indexDB etc.) under the user's home directory, depending on your operating system:

**Windows**: `C:\Users\<you>\AppData\Local\<Your App Name>`
**macOS**: `~/Library/Application Support/<Your App Name>`
**Linux**: `~/.config/<Your App Name>`

Unless you change your application name or otherwise purge your database these files will still be there after each update.